# How to use google maps navigation voice output as input to another android application

Tags: android, google-maps, arduino, arduino-uno

Google is not giving it's API for turn by turn navigation.To one of my university project I'm arduino connected hand glove to get call notification,health monitoring and most importantly navigation.

I made all the call notification,heath monitoring parts but I can't figure it out how to notify to user when a turn come to "Left" Indicate using a LED bulb.

I have an idea like this:
If I can get google maps navigation voice output as input to make a strings like "Left" or "Right"I can Indicate using that strings.

Currently I don't have codes on this.

p.s : Here maps and other maps are not using only google maps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226112/how-to-use-google-maps-navigation-voice-output-as-input-to-another-android-appli). I unfortunately don't think this is possible.

Comment: I am sorry for duplication but I want to know weather is there any other functionalities I can add to this project .I really need another options because I'm out of options.